# Use Composer without Packagist

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

Say for instance you want to use a bundle from someone else, but want to do some modifications. So you do your modifications in some new branch, and configure comspoer.json like:

```
{
    "require": {
        "sylius/assortment-bundle": "dev-soft-deleteable-products-disabled"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "sylius/assortment-bundle",
                "version": "1.0",
                "autoload": { "psr-0": { "Sylius\\Bundle\\AssortmentBundle": "" } },
                "target-dir": "Sylius/Bundle/AssortmentBundle",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/umpirsky/SyliusAssortmentBundle.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "soft-deleteable-products-disabled"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This works with master branch, but with custom branch it gives: `The requested package sylius/assortment-bundle dev-soft-deleteable-products-disabled could not be found.`

Any idea?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should really be using a VCS repository instead of the package repository. Package is for when there is no composer.json and you want to specify it inline instead. In your case there is a composer.json, so you can use the VCS repo, like so:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/umpirsky/SyliusAssortmentBundle"
    }
]
```

Composer will in this case use the GitHub API to fetch the branch names and check if the version `dev-soft-deleteable-products-disabled` exists. If it does, it will clone the repository and check out said branch.

Hopefully if you do this as a side effect your problem will be fixed as well.

For more information read the docs [chapter on repositories](http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md).

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Didn't know that repos can be defined like that, that's awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Satis can be used as a micro version of Packagist - allowing you to centrally control your Composer dependancies for private repositories.

[Composer Guide to Satis Usage](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md#satis)