# git add an existing git folder to parent project

Tags: git, github

I have a project in github, I want to include that project to my company's big project.
Structure like as (`bigproject` must conatin `myproject`'s files):

```
bigproject/.git
bigproject/myproject/.git
```

I clone my project to `bigproject/myproject/.git`, and `git add .` under `bigproject`. That command just add `myproject` folder without the contain.

I'd like to update `myproject` on github, and just add change to my company's `bigproject`.I search around and find `git submodule`, but the official document is not obvious.
What should I do?

The expected follow is:

```
bigproject/myproject/.git     git pull origin master
bigproject/.git               git add .
bigproject/.git               git push
```

Comment: You can import it with composer.Here is some more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229970/use-composer-without-packagist

Comment: @Dieter Pollier `myproject` is not just a package.My colleague may alter the code sometime, I also want push the changes to github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the root of bigproject you may add `myproject` as a submodule of `bigproject`

```
git submodule add <url to myproject repo> myproject`
git add .
git commit -m "adding myproject"
git submodule init
git submodule update
```