# I've created a Laravel package but it cannot be installed by Composer

Tags: php, laravel, repository, composer-php, package

I've created a package in GitHub and want to install to my Laravel project but it errors and cannot to be installed!

I called this statement in console:

```
composer require larabook/laravelgateways
```

But it errors:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>     Could not find package larabook/laravelgateways at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability

And here is my package's `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "larabook/laravelgateways",
    "homepage": "https://github.com/larabook/laravelgateways",
    "description": "A Laravel package for connecting to all Iraninan payments gateways",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Hamed Pakdaman",
            "email": "pakdaman.it@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "Larabook\\PoolPort\\": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "PoolPort/PoolPort" : "3.0.*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to publish your package at [Packagist](https://packagist.org/) before it can be found by Composer. Do This first if you want to publish it for everyone.

In the case this package is only meant for you, or it is for testing purposes only then don't use Packagist. See [how to Use Composer without Packagist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229970/use-composer-without-packagist) for using your package directly from GitHub without publishing at Packagist.

Make sure your Git project has a version tag (if you are on `"minimum-stability": "stable"`) or you set `"minimum-stability": "dev"`.
Create a tag e.g. `git tag -a 1.0.0 -m 'First version.'` and push it to GitHub `git push --tags`.

Comment: yes, I've installed it , but no effect!

https://packagist.org/packages/larabook/laravelgateways

Comment: You didn't create a version tag in your GitHub project. Composer determines the version of a package by its tags. You defined `"minimum-stability": "stable"` there is no version tag, so it can't find any stable version. Set stability to `dev` or better create a version tag (e.g. `git tag -a 1.0.0 -m 'First version.'`) and push it to your GitHub project (e.g. `git push --tags`).

Comment: same error ! I released new version 1.0.0 and updated packagist then run these below statements :

Comment: composer require larabook/laravelgateways

Comment: also set "minimum-stability": "dev"