# Could not find a matching version of package when require my created package laravel

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm newbie, i have created a laravel package but i can't require to install it.

When I try to install this package using `composer require spider/spider-reporter:@dev` I get below error

```
 [InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                                                                         
  Could not find a matching version of package spider/spider-reporter. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which m  
  atches your minimum-stability (dev).
```

In `composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "spider/reporter",
    "description": "reporter spider",
    "type": "project",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "duykhanh",
            "email": "ngoduykhanh@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Spider\\Reporter\\": "./src"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "@php ./vendor/bin/testbench package:discover --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "Spider\\Reporter\\SpiderReporterServiceProvider"
            ]
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

And I added to main `composer.json` file in the root

```
"require": {
    "spider/spider-reporter": "@dev"
},

"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Spider\\Reporter\\": "platform/spider-reporter/src"
        }
    },

"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "./platform/spider-reporter",
            "options": {
                "symlink": true
            }
        }
]
```

I ran `php artisan dump-autoload` and `composer update` but it's not working.

Hope everyone can help me, thank all!!

Comment: can you give the link of that package? i cannot find it.

Comment: Hi Kaptian, this package is for testing purposes and I can't register on packagist beacause I don't have permission to public Repositories of my company. I'm so sorry

Comment: as far as i know, if you use `composer require vendor/package` command, it will look at the packages registered/submitted at `packagist.org`.

Comment: I have referenced the following article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36976939/ive-created-a-laravel-package-but-it-cannot-be-installed-by-composer

Comment: You're using incorrect names - you named your package `spider/reporter`, but you're requiring `spider/spider-reporter`.

Comment: Hi rob006. Thank you very much, I fixed it successfully